# Getting endless loop in PHP

Tags: php

Whenever i try to run this code, it seems like it gets into an endless loop. But, i cant figure out whats causing this problem. Maybe an extra eye on the thing would be able do point out the problem?

The problem only accours when there is a different year zone, example 2012-2018

Example: $this->budget_model->set_monthly_budget('1','2012', '8','2014','1');

```
    function set_monthly_budget($start_month, $start_year, $end_month, $end_year, $budget_group_id)
{

    $user_id = 2;

    // Current date
    $current_month = $start_month;
    $current_year = $start_year;
    $days_in_current_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $current_month, $current_year);
    $company_id = 1;
    $month_goal = 100;

    // Check if it is the current month
    if($start_year == $end_year)
    {

        for($x=$current_month;$x<=$end_month;$x++)
        {

            $data = array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'budget_group_id' => $budget_group_id,
                'month' => $x,
                'year' => $start_year,
                'company_id' => $company_id,
                'month_goal' => $month_goal
            );

            // Inserting information into the database
            $this->db->insert('budget_month',$data);

        }

        return true; // Return true if the task was completed

    }

    if($start_year !== $end_year)
    {

        $temp_start_year = $start_year;

        while($temp_start_year !== $end_year)
        {

            // Check if we are in the same year as we started
            if($temp_start_year == $current_year)
            {

                // Insert remaining months for this year
                for($x=$current_month;$x<=12;$x++)
                {

                    $data = array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'budget_group_id' => $budget_group_id,
                        'month' => $x,
                        'year' => $temp_start_year,
                        'company_id' => $company_id,
                        'month_goal' => $month_goal
                    );

                    // Inserting information into the database
                    $this->db->insert('budget_month',$data);

                }

            }

            // Check if the temp and end year is the same
            if($temp_start_year < $end_year)
            {

                // Insert remaining months for this year
                for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++)
                {

                    $data = array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'budget_group_id' => $budget_group_id,
                        'month' => $x,
                        'year' => $temp_start_year,
                        'company_id' => $company_id,
                        'month_goal' => $month_goal
                    );

                    // Inserting information into the database
                    $this->db->insert('budget_month',$data);

                }

            }

            // Check if we are in the same year as we started

            if($temp_start_year == $end_year)
            {

                // Insert remaining months for this year
                for($x=1;$x<=$end_month;$x++)
                {

                    $data = array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'budget_group_id' => $budget_group_id,
                        'month' => $x,
                        'year' => $temp_start_year,
                        'company_id' => $company_id,
                        'month_goal' => $month_goal
                    );

                    // Inserting information into the database
                    $this->db->insert('budget_month',$data);

                }

            }

            $temp_start_year++;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If `$start_year` is greater than `$end_year`, the while loop's condition will always be fulfilled, making in an endless loop.

Comment: Your code above has two loops. use some `echo` statements to narrow down which of the two loops is not terminating.

Answer (score 6):

in your code

```
while($temp_start_year !== $end_year)
```

you used !== which also check if the type of the 2 variables are the same.

but this line

```
$temp_start_year++;
```

will implicitly cast the variable to integer.

Therefore the !== will be comparing integer to string, which will always evaluate to true.

The solution is as simple as using != instead of !==, or feed an integer instead of string when you call your function (remove the single quotes).